# Can I watch a controller scope property from inside a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Assuming that this watch is inside a directive is it possible to watch a variable from the main controller like this? Here is the whole directive. When it looks like this the watch does get triggered on the first page load but then never again. I do not pass questionNumber to the directive. Is this why it is not aware of it?

```
    .directive('videoLoader', function () {
return function (scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(attrs.videoLoader, function () {
        element[0].load();
        element[0].play();
        $(scope.video).bind('ended', function () {
            $(this).unbind('ended');
            if (!this.ended) {
                return;
            }
            scope.tutorialNumber++;
            scope.$apply();
            scope.loadFromMenu();
        });
    });
    scope.$watch(scope.questionNumber, function(){
        if (scope.sectionNumber === 0 && scope.tutorialNumber === 0) { //if first video play congratulations etc
            if (scope.questionNumber === 1) {
                start(164.15);
                pause(166.8);
            } else if (scope.questionNumber === 2) {
                start(167.1);
                pause(170);
            } else if (scope.questionNumber === 3) {
                start(171.1);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

})

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your directive is not creating a new scope or an isolate scope, it uses the scope that is in affect where the directive is used in the HTML.  If `controls` is a directive and it creates a new or isolate scope, then the video-loader directive will also use that scope.  This might explain why @rajkamal's answer didn't work for you.

If `controls` is not a directive, than video-loader will use the controller's scope (unless you have video-loader in an ng-repeat or some other directive that creates a child scope.)  Without showing us more of your HTML, it is not possible to determine what scope your directive will get.

Here is [a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qPk51fR0kLBqV7xTXDME?p=preview) showing how a video-loader directive, used inside a controller scope, has access to that scope (in particular, a `questionNumber` property).

Although it might take some time getting used to jsfiddle and plunker, I highly recommend spending the time.  People can help you much faster if you have a jsfiddle or plunker.

Comment: I will bare that in mind, it's not that I dont get plunker at all, its just that this particular app doesnt really work if you start taking bits out, nothing really works independently. Anyway thanks for the great answer

Answer (score 3):

`scope.$watch('questionNumber', function(newValue, oldValue){//something}`. I havent tried out an example before posting this, but i remember trying like this before.

Please note that `scope.$watch(scope.questionNumber...` is now `scope.$watch('questionNumber'...`

Comment: questionnumber comes up undefined, scope.questionNumber gives a number as it should but is still not triggering the watch

Comment: could you prepare a jsfiddle. That could help me see the problem

Comment: I can't it depends on videos and honestly I have never got my app to work in fiddle or plunker!

Comment: You don't need to recreate your whole app in jsFiddle. That would actually be counterproductive. Use jsFiddle/Plunker to only recreate the specifc controller/directive/watch problem. Possibly without video controls.

Comment: dude honestly the amount of time I have spent pissing around with fiddle and plunker to no avail is worse than the problem itself. All I want to know is this: "is it possible to watch a variable from the main  app controller from within a directive?

Comment: sorry for the ambiguity guys, see answer below if you're interested

Comment: its fine. im trying to get the answer.. its not working for me too.. i will post the answer if its working for me

Answer (score 0):

hallelujah I've done it! The answer is no, apparently directives can't see into scopes of other controllers, they have to be passed in via attributes in the HTML, this was fine with just one attribute but I was struggling to get 2 in, turns out it can be done like this

```
<video video-loader class="video-js vjs-default-skin" id="myvideo" congrats="questionNumber" video-loader="tutorialNumber" id="video" controls>
    <source type="video/mp4" src="{{videoURLs[tutorialNumber]}}.mp4"></source>
    <source type="video/webm" src="{{videoURLs[tutorialNumber]}}.webm"></source>
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Then accessed inside the directive with a second $watch like so:

```
directive('videoLoader', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.videoLoader, function () {
            element[0].load();
            element[0].play();
            $(scope.video).bind('ended', function () {
                $(this).unbind('ended');
                if (!this.ended) {
                    return;
                }
                scope.tutorialNumber++;
                scope.$apply();
                scope.loadFromMenu();
            });
        });
        scope.$watch(attrs.congrats, function(){    
            scope.questionNumber;
            if (scope.sectionNumber === 0 && scope.tutorialNumber === 0) { //if first video play congratulations etc
                if (scope.questionNumber === 1) {
                    start(164.15);
                    pause(166.8);
                } else if (scope.questionNumber === 2) {
                    start(167.1);
                    pause(170);
                } else if (scope.questionNumber === 3) {
                    start(171.1);
                }
            }
        });
    };
})
```

Comment: The answer is 'sometimes': directives can see controller scopes under certain conditions.  See my answer for details.

Comment: You used `video-loader` twice on the same element.  Typo?